# how to understand the wifi code flow in android?

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi

I am new to the android. I just want to understand the Wi-Fi code flow in android. I have already grasp some basic stuff about it, need some more detail about it.

Comment: What you want to research on Wifi android ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a good starting point..
https://source.android.com/devices/tech/connect/wifi-overview

Answer (score 0):

Hi thanks for the Question.
before i answer your question i wanted some calrification?
you want to learn wifi for app developement or you want understand wifi has a whole module?
if your perpose is to understand has a whole from app layer to driver.
i would suggest you to look into this 
[https://www.amazon.com/802-11-Wireless-Networks-Definitive-Guide-ebook/dp/B005WZ0SXW](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005WZ0SXW)
even before you jump into code.
has far has the code is concerned 
these are few things which i would suggest you to look into.

1)Wpa_supplicant is an open source project source code, which was modified by Google to join theAndroidmobile platform.
What is wpa_spplicant ?-->start from here .
practice how to use wpa supplicant from cmd line.

2)once you have got the grip on wpa_supplicant wireless network configuration form cmd line or linux terminal.

3)next will suggest you to look into android architecture  the one before android N and after Treble.

4)once you are familiar with architecture,please look into state machine and how they are making state transistion form one state to other.-->in framework code from android M(easy compared to latest).

and so on .these are just few things which can help you ,but there is a lot more happening and its vast.